# How to Use CheckBox Logic to navigate other sheets in a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a few checkboxes , based on the "True" or "False" logic of the checkboxes , I would like to navigate to different "Sheets" in a same workbook. Please Help in writing a VBA code !!

I have written the following code,But I get a "OBJECT" error.

```
 If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = True Then Sheets("abc").Range("A3").Select
```

Comment: Object Error? Are you using ActiveX Controls or Form Controls?

Comment: Ya object Error , I am using ActiveX Controls.

Comment: Can you try the code that I posted?

Comment: Also how did you insert the checkbox and where is the checkbox? In a form or in the worksheet?

Comment: or can you post a screenshot of the controls?

Comment: I used your code with the "Form Controls" . Its working :) . Thank you so much,I mean it :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: What was the issue with my code ? I used ActiveX Controls.Just for my knowledge pls.

Comment: No. Those are not ActiveX controls. Those are form controls. I would recommend reading up online to see the difference :)

Comment: Okay sounds good :) Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you are using form controls.

Try this for me.

```
Dim cbOne As Shape, cbTwo As Shape

Set cbOne = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1")
Set cbTwo = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2")

If cbOne.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 And cbTwo.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
   '
   '~~> Do what you want
   '
End If
```